# Pandas merge two data frame only to first occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe, I am able to merge by `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='column_name')`. But I only want to merge on first occurrence  in `df1` Any pointer or solution? It's a many to one, and I only want the first occurrence merged. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide your ```df1``` and ```df2``` in a [reproducible way](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and also add an example of what your output should be? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to merge two dataframes of different lengths, you'll have to have `NaN` values in the merged dataframe cells where there are no corresponding indices in `df2`. So let's try this. Merge left. This will duplicate `df2` values for duplicated `column_name` rows in `df1`. Have a mask ready to filter those rows and assign `NaN` for them in the columns from `df2`.

```
mask = df1['column_name'].duplicated()
new_df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='column_name')
new_df.loc[mask, df2.columns[df2.columns!='column_name']] = np.nan
```

Comment: This worked for me, with the use df1['column_name'].duplicated()  can work on this. But for future reference, how can we achieve something similar to df1['column_name'].duplicated()if I want to compare two keys?

Comment: @KaizLee since keys are duplicate, you can't really compare the keys themselves but you compare on indices, that's why `.duplicated` works.