# Duplicated rows while Merging in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two datasets :

`df2`

| Claim |
|:------|
| ABC   |
| ABC   |
| ABC   |
| AAC   |
| AAC   |
| AAC   |
| AAC   |
| ADC   |
| ADC   |
| ADC   |
`df1`

| Claim | Flag |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 |
| AAC | 0 |
| ADC | 1 |

While merging I am expecting , that only first instance gets the flag value but all the duplicates are getting the flag value

I have tried

```py
df3 = pd.merge(df2,df1[['Claim','Flag']],on='Claim', how='left')
```

I am expecting an output as :

| Claim | Flag |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 |
| ABC |  |
| ABC |  |
| AAC | 0 |
| AAC |  |
| AAC |  |
| AAC |  |
| ADC | 1 |
| ADC |  |
| ADC |  |

But I am getting this instead:

| Claim | Flag |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 |
| ABC | 1 |
| ABC | 1 |
| AAC | 0 |
| AAC | 0 |
| AAC | 0 |
| AAC | 0 |
| ADC | 1 |
| ADC | 1 |
| ADC | 1 |

Can someone please help with this urgently

Comment: A non-elegant solution would be to split your dataframe into the duplicates and the non-duplicates/first duplicate, merge, and then concatenate. You'd use `DataFrame.duplicated(keep = 'first')` and then split your dataframe based on that, perform the merge, and then use `pd.concat`.

Comment: Since it is a big dataset I am trying to avoid splitting the data frames

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following solution: collect the indexes of the first elements, and then insert values according to these indexes.

First we collect the index sheet:

```py
indexes = [df1[df1['Claim'] == claim].head(1).index for claim in df2['Claim']]
```

Then we calculate the Flag column using apply. If the index is not in the array, return np.na (NaN value):

```py
df1['Flag'] = df1.apply(lambda x: df2[df2['Claim'] == x['Claim']]['Flag'].to_list()[0] if x.name in indexes else np.nan, axis=1)
```

Just in case, I will warn you: you must have the numpy library connected (for NaN value).

```py
import numpy as np
```

You can also insert an empty string instead of NaN.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Create a dictionary for claim flag mapping
claim_flag_map = dict(list(zip(df1.Claim, df1.Flag)))

flags = [] 
claims_check = []

for row in df2.itertuples():
    if row[1] not in claims_check and row[1] in claim_flag_map:
        flags.append(claim_flag_map[row[1]])
        claims_check.append(row[1])
    else:
        flags.append("")
df2["Flag"] =  flags
```

df2 should match your expected output.

Here is a better solution that I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70392299/7748451).

```
import numpy as np
df3=df2.merge(df1, how='left', on='Claim' )
mask = df3['Flag'].duplicated()
df3.loc[mask, df3.columns[df3.columns!='Claim']] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below:

```
claim_1 = ['ABC','ABC','ABC','AAC','AAC','AAC','AAC','ADC','ADC','ADC']
claim_2 = ['ABC','AAC','ADC']
flag = [1,0,1]

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Claim':claim_1})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Claim':claim_2,'Flag':flag})

df_1['rank'] = df_1.groupby('Claim')['Claim'].cumcount()
df_2['rank'] = df_2.groupby(['Claim','Flag']).cumcount()

df_1.merge(df_2, left_on=['Claim','rank'], right_on=['Claim','rank'], how='left')[['Claim','Flag']]
```

Answer (score 0):

try `join` instead of `merge`

```
d1 = {'Claim': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'AAC','AAC','AAC','AAC','ADC','ADC','ADC']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2 = {'Claim': ['ABC', 'AAC', 'ADC'], 'Flag': [1,0,1]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

df3 = df1.join(df2,  lsuffix='_caller', rsuffix='_other')
df3.drop('Claim_other',inplace=True, axis=1)
df3
```

[image]